# Config changes only propagated via manual form submit

Tags: 8, search, configuration

My question is related to the Search API Drupal 8 module. I am modifying my configuration via config file updates. After I am installing my custom module, I can see my config reflected in the search index field settings via the configuration form. However, after I re-index I cannot find content via my newly defined fields. This works only, if I open the search index fields configuration form and submit it manually via webbrowser. No config changes - just hitting the save button.

Tried clearing the cache, entity updates, rebuild tracking information, rebuild the search index - nothing helps.

Can I implement anything into hook_install() from my custom module to propagate the necessary config changes properly to my database?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved it by myself. I am re-saving the search index by myself via hook_install().

```
  $index_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('search_api_index');
  $index = $index_storage->load('search_content');
  $index->save();
```